# If $f:A\to A'$ and $g:B\to B'$ are isomorphisms, then the tensor product is also an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products, tensors

My book has the following theorem:

> Theorem 7.7:
>
> If $f:A\to A'$ and $g:B\to B'$ are epimorphisms of modules over $R$,
>   then the tensor product
>
> $$h = f\otimes g:A\otimes B\to A'\otimes B'$$
>
> is also an epimorphism and its kernel $Ker(h)$ is the submodule $K$ of $A\otimes B$ generated by the elements $a\otimes b$ of $A\otimes B$ with $a\in Ker(f)$ or $b\in Ker(g)$

And then says that the following corollary is an immediate consequence of 7.7:

> Corollary 7.8:
>
> If $f:A\to A'$ and $g:B\to B'$ are isomorphisms of modules over $R$,
>   then the tensor product
>
> $$h = f\otimes g:A\otimes B\to A'\otimes B'$$
>
> is also an isomorphism

I understand that if $f$ and $g$ are epimorphisms, then $h$ is also an epimorphism. In the corollary, it must be an isomorphism, that is, monomorphism and epimorphism. The epimorphism part is from the theorem 7.7, but how do I argue about the monomorphism part? I guess it has something to do with the kernel part of the theorem 7.7, but I cannot connect the ideas.

Comment: What book is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms then their kernels are trivial. Therefore, the kernel of $f\otimes g$ is trivial by that part of 7.7.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: if $f: A \rightarrow A'$ is an isomorphism, then it has an inverse $f^{-1}: A' \rightarrow A$.  The same for $g$.  Check that

$$f \otimes g \circ f^{-1} \otimes g^{-1} = (f \circ f^{-1}) \otimes (g \circ g^{-1}) = 1_{A'} \otimes 1_{B'} = 1_{A' \otimes B'}$$

And by the same reasoning, $f^{-1} \otimes g^{-1} \circ f \otimes g = 1_{A \otimes B}$.  This shows that $f \otimes g$ is a bijection.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the preferable approach as it is direct and works in arbitrary monoidal categories. It is, of course, not connected to the given theorem as it holds in a far more general context.