# Symplectic structure on tensor products and duals

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Suppose $(V,\omega_V)$ and $(W,\omega_W)$ are two finite-dimensional real symplectic vector spaces. I want to know how I can define new symplectic structures.

I know $V\oplus W$ comes with a natural symplectic form $\omega_V \oplus \omega_W$. How can I define symplectic structures on tensor products and dual spaces?

I have been looking around and haven't found anything regarding this issue.

Comment: For dual spaces it's easy. Take your $(V,\omega_V)$, for example. For each $f\in V^*$ there is a unique vector $\Phi(f)\in V$ such that $f(w) = \omega_V(\Phi(f), w)$ for any $w\in V$. The map $\Phi$ is easily seen to be a isomorphism (using that $\omega_V$ is bilinear and non-degenerate) between $V^*$ and $V$, so you can use it to transport the symplectic form $\omega_V$ from $V$ to $V^*$.  For each $f,g\in V^*$, the transported symplectic form $\omega_{V}^*$ is given by $\omega_V^*(f,g) = \omega_V(\Phi(f), \Phi(g))$.

Comment: Thanks! Of course I have forgotten that symplectic forms induce a musical isomorphism with the dual. 

I am currently trying to set it up for tensor products, but I cannot prove non-degeneracy of the naïve form $\omega_V\otimes \omega_W$.

Comment: I have an idea for that. Let $\phi_V: V\rightarrow V^*$, $\phi_W: W\rightarrow W^*$ the musical maps of $\omega_V, \omega_W$. If $\omega$ is the naïve form, consider the "musical map" $\phi: V\otimes W \rightarrow (V\otimes W)^*$ associated to $\omega$:


$$\phi(v\otimes w)(v'\otimes w')= \omega(v\otimes w, v'\otimes w') = \omega_V(v,v')\omega_W(w,w') = \phi_V(v)(v')\phi_W(w)(w') =$$

$$= [(\phi_V(v)\otimes\phi_W(w))](v'\otimes w') = [(\phi_V\otimes\phi_W)(v\otimes w)](v'\otimes w')$$

Comment: this kinda shows $\phi = \phi_V\otimes \phi_W$, and since $\phi_V$, $\phi_W$ are isomorphisms, their tensor product is also an isomorphism according to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2300893/if-fa-to-a-and-gb-to-b-are-isomorphisms-then-the-tensor-product-is-also

Comment: Since its musical map is bijective, then $\omega$ must be non degenerate. If this convinces you, I will post it as answer.

Comment: It convinces me that $\phi$ is an isomorphism between $(V\otimes W)$ and $(V\otimes W)^*$; however, now that I think about it the naïve 2-form **is not skew-symmetric**! How can we overcome this?

If you address this issue I will be happy to accept the answer, of course. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, I didn't check that. Then you have to define it by other means. I once studied how a (symmetric and positive definite) form on a space $V$ could be transported to the space of tensors on $V$ by taking an orthonormal basis in $V$ and then declaring that each associated basis of tensors to be orthonormal. That is, I think, the only "natural" way of defining a symplectic form on $V\otimes W$: take "orthonormal" (canonical) bases $\lbrace v_i\rbrace$, $\lbrace w_j\rbrace$ of $V$, $W$ and then there's only one symplectic form such that the basis $\lbrace v_i\otimes w_j\rbrace$  is orthonormal.

Comment: An "orthonormal" or canonical basis, is a basis where the symplectic form is represented by the standard matrix: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f56f1a2154adeab55502db50289f4f21bc780899  Where $I_n$ is the identity matrix (the space $V$ has dimension $2n$).

Comment: Then one should check that this definition of associated symplectic form on $V\otimes W$ is "natural". That means that if $\lbrace v_i'\rbrace$, $\lbrace w_j'\rbrace$ are other orthonormal bases of $V$, $W$, then $\lbrace v_i'\otimes w_j'\rbrace$ should also be orthonormal. I don't know if this is true, and seems very tedious.

Comment: I thank you deeply for your trouble. I have partially solved my motivating problem, which was not so much solving the problem in general but building a symplectic form on the space of linear maps $Hom(V,W)\simeq V\otimes W^*$.

It turns out that I can do so, after endowing $V$ and $W$ with Hermitian metrics  by declaring a Hermitian metric for linear maps given by $h(\phi,\psi) = Tr(\phi\psi^\dagger)$ to obtain a linear Hermitian structure and a 2-form via
$h = g -i \omega$. This solves my motivating problem (although it doesn't answer the question).